# How to show $a$ and $b$ are different??

Tags: calculus, analysis

We have a continuously differenciable function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$ such that $f(0)=0, f(1)=1$. We need to show that there exists different real numbers $a,b\in(0,1)$ such that $f'(a)f'(b)=1.$

I used the mean value theorem as follows: There exists $\alpha\in(0,1)$ such that $(f\circ f)'(\alpha)=1$, that is to say, $f'(f(\alpha))f'(\alpha)=1$. Let $a=f(\alpha)$ and $b=\alpha$. Then, $f'(a)f'(b)=1$. But I didn't use the continuity of the derivative, and a don't know how to show that $a\neq b$.
Thanks, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think you might need to change your approach slightly, since if $f(x) = x,$ then $a=b$ no matter what $\alpha$ is in your construction.

Answer (score 1):

All we need is to find a point where the graph crosses the diagonal line $x+y=1.$ Then we will apply MVT on both sides of that point.

Take
$$ g(x) = x + f(x) - 1.  $$
We get $$ g(0) = -1, \; \; \; g(1) = 1. $$
By the Intermediate Value Theorem, for some $0 < t < 1$ we get $g(t) = 0,$ meaning
$ t + f(t) - 1 = 0 $ or
$$  f(t) = 1-t $$
Note that $1-t \neq 0,$ indeed $0 < 1-t < 1.$

By the mean value theorem, there is a value $a$ between $0$ and $t$ so that $$f'(a) = \frac{1-t}{t}$$
There is also a value $b$ between $t$ and $1$ such that
$$f'(b) = \frac{1-(1-t)}{1-t} =\frac{t}{1-t} $$

Comment: Well, but do not we need the hypotesis about continuity of the derivative?

Comment: @DIEGOR. if your question had said "continuously differentiable" I would probably have tried to use that.  However, you wrote "continuous differenciable" and I was not sure what was going on. I decided it meant "continuous and differentiable" Anyway, you just need enough to call on the Mean Value Theorem.

Comment: @WillJagy:  I wondered about that as well, but since differentiable implies continuous, I figured the OP was *not* being redundant and hence assumed "continuously differentiable" was intended.

Comment: Yes I have edited it. I think that we do not need the continuity of derivative according with this proof. Thanks